# Cannot compare elements of type 'System.Linq.IQueryable`1'. Only primitive types, enumeration types and entity types are supported

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, asp.net-mvc-4

i have this code in my controller

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult Nabipour()
{
    string name = "Nabipour";
    var username = (from T in _db.tbl_teacher
                    where T.Page==name
                    select T.Username);
    ViewBag.Nabipour = from N in _db.tbl_Tpage
                        where N.Username.Equals(username)
                        select N;
    ViewBag.papers = from P in _db.tbl_Tpaper
                     where P.Username.Equals(username)
                     select P;

    return View();
}
```

and this is my view for this action:

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Nabipour";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_otherpage.cshtml";
}
....
<ul>
    @foreach (var paper in ViewBag.papers)
    {
        <li><a href="~/Content/Paper/@paper.PaperName"></a></li>
    }                 
</ul>
....
```

so as you see i not checking null in my select code and i tried this code with `.FirstOrDefault()` in the select. the error

> Cannot compare elements of type 'System.Linq.IQueryable 1 . Only primitive types, enumeration types and entity types are supported

is on `@foreach (var paper in ViewBag.papers)` please help me what should i do?

Comment: Why are you using ViewBag instead of a strongly typed view with a proper model?

Comment: @DavidG because i need to use 2 model for this view .i not write the code yet. if it was just 1 model you right  i was use a strongly typed view. but now i need ViewBag to send this information from both of models

Comment: Use a view model with all the properties your need, not `ViewBag`

Comment: Your error occurs because `username` is `IQuerable`,  not a `string`. You need `var username = (from T in _db.tbl_teacher where T.Page==name select T.Username).FirstOrDefault();`

Comment: @StephenMuecke thanks i will check it now!

Comment: @StephenMuecke i tried `var username = (from T in _db.tbl_teacher where T.Page==name select T.Username).FirstOrDefault();` but now i have this error `Object reference not set to an instance of an object.` is this mean the `ViewBag` is null?

Comment: What is the value of `username` when you use that code? Are there any `tbl_teacher` items with  `T.Page=="Nabipour"`?

Comment: @StephenMuecke i have a table named `tbl_teacher` for teachers. every teacher have an unique `Username` and also every teachers have another table for uploading papers in site. and i use `Username` to recognize which paper is for which teacher .  `T.Page=="Nabipour"` existe but this teacher haven't any paper! i checked the table data from server explore ! i'm so Wacky ! sorry! :-D so the error was  for null reference! thanks for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult Nabipour()
{
    string name = "Nabipour";
    var username = (from T in _db.tbl_teacher
                    where T.Page==name
                    select T.Username).FirstOrDefault();
    ViewBag.Nabipour = from N in _db.tbl_Tpage
                        where N.Username.Equals(username)
                        select N;
    ViewBag.papers = (from P in _db.tbl_Tpaper
                     where P.Username.Equals(username)
                     select P).ToList();

    return View();
}
```